# Android Videoview AsyncTask: Activity crashes when go back to previous activity

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-videoview

I having a problem when I press back my Activity crashes. I have also initialized `isPLaying = false` above `onCreate` method. I have also initialized `isPlaying = true` after `videoview.start()` and `isPlaying= false` `onStop` method.

So, what is happen is when open the activity the video starts playing with no problem but when i press back or close the activity it crashes.

```
private class MyAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void>
    {
        int duration = 0;
        int current = 0;
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            if (isPlaying) {
                videoView4.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {

                    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                        duration = videoView4.getDuration();
                    }
                });

                do {
                    if (isPlaying) {
                        current = videoView4.getCurrentPosition();
                        System.out.println("duration - " + duration + " current- "
                                + current);
                        try {
                            publishProgress((int) (current * 100 / duration));
                            if(videoPB.getProgress() >= 100){
                                break;
                            }
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                        }
                    }

                } while (videoPB.getProgress() <= 100);

            }


            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
            if (isPlaying) {
                System.out.println(values[0]);
                videoPB.setProgress(values[0]);
            }

        }
    }
```

Here is the logcat of the activity

```
>     2019-08-17 22:18:51.854 6753-6913/com.example.debarunlahiri.burnab E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
>         Process: com.example.debarunlahiri.burnab, PID: 6753
>         java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
>             at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:354)
>             at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:383)
>             at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:252)
>             at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:271)
>             at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245)
>             at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
>             at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
>             at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
>          Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException
>             at android.media.MediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition(Native Method)
>             at android.widget.VideoView.getCurrentPosition(VideoView.java:817)
>             at com.example.debarunlahiri.burnab.VideoActivity$MyAsync.doInBackground(VideoActivity.java:204)
>             at com.example.debarunlahiri.burnab.VideoActivity$MyAsync.doInBackground(VideoActivity.java:189)
>             at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333)
>             at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>             at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245) 
>             at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
>             at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
>             at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Comment: [link]https://docs.google.com/document/d/1abVCOHjI_-QxNm8l_lA9gUaFy1sTG6oJKXc2YUfaytQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: In do in background....current = videoView4.getCurrentPosition();...In this line .....put code:if(videoView!=null){...}

Comment: getting error on `current = videoView4.getCurrentPosition();`

Comment: Please try to put if(videoView4!=null)  inside your do in Background.....and also stop task of aysnc task in onPause method.